# How to make pointer reference to array work?

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
int gRealArray[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int*& gArrayPtrTest = *reinterpret_cast<int**>(gRealArray);

ASSERT_EQ(gArrayPtrTest[0], 1);
ASSERT_EQ(gArrayPtrTest[1], 2);
```

I expect that gArrayPtrTest[0] should be the same as gRealArray[0], however instead it crashes because the value of the pointer is 1. What is the correct way to get a int*& that lets me use the [] operator to access the pointed to array?

Comment: What is the purpose for this?

Comment: I'm casting some arbitrary address in a hook to to int*&, I know its an array but I don't know the size yet. So I want to use the pointer as if it was an array, which I'm sure should work? Edit - hence this small test case without casting random 0xdeadbeef locations to it.

Comment: Unless I am missing something if the address represents an `int` array then you can just `int* foo = address_of_array`

Comment: This is true, but if foo is assigned to another address then it won't update the pointed to address, hence the *&

Comment: Well you can always make it an `int * const foo = address_of_array` to stop that.

Comment: @paulm But an array isn't a pointer, you can't update an array to point at something else.

Comment: No but if I have a pointer to an array then I can point it to a new array?

Comment: Where on God's green earth the `**` come from? In order to have `**` you need to take an address of a pointer, but your code contains no suitable pointers.

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want, you need a `const` reference to an `int` pointer.  Using your example:

```
int* const& gArrayPtrTest = gRealArray;
```

This is because `gRealArray` is an `int` array and can be correctly, implicitly cast to a pointer to an `int` but not a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.  But since you want a reference to the pointer, it needs to be a const reference.  I'm not sure how to explain why, but I think it has something to do with the fact that the pointer is a rvalue expression.  In other words, this would compile and run correctly:

```
int *foo = gRealArray;
int *& gArrayPtrTest  = foo;
```

But this does not:

```
int *& gArrayPtrTest  = gRealArray;
```

Because the pointer is not stored in memory anywhere; it's the result of an implicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

The reference has to point to something.  In the example code, you are trying to create a reference that doesn't have an l-value to point.  Consider this: if you set gArrayPtrTest to something else, what variable actually gets updated?  C++ will allow this if gArrayPtrTest is defined as a const, since it can manage the r-value behind the scenes.  Other than const, a reference has to refer to something.  And, C++ will handle the referencing for you, so reinterpret_cast is not needed (and very dangerous to try to use!).

Create the variable that holds the actual pointer address, and then create a reference to that.  The reference is not const in this example, so it can be pointed to something else later:

```
int gRealArray[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int * gAddressOfArray = gRealArray;
int* & gArrayPtrTest = gAddressOfArray;
```

And in this case, if you later decide to write:

```
int gAnotherRealArray[10] = { -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10 };
gArrayPtrTest = gAnotherRealArray;
```